# How to install cordova(phonegap) ios app to device via cli and not via xcode

Tags: ios, cordova, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a simple project with last phonegap version:

```
$ phonegap create my-project
$ phonegap build ios
$ phonegap install ios
```

All works perfectly and I see emulator with my simple application.

But I can't find documentation on how to run my application **on device**(iphone, for example) and not on a simulator.

All documentation by cordova / phonegap based on examples with cordova's template for xcode.
But last cordova's version don't have template for xcode and all that I need  - cli, if I understand correctly?

I already registered as IOS developer and I have a valid iPhone development certificate.
When I connect my device - I can see it in xcode and I can run native application on my device.
But only via xcode.

I will be grateful to any advice.

Comment: See this link may be useful:1)http://www.gajotres.net/creating-phonegap-project-on-macos/

Comment: Thanks dude, but your example associated with xcode. Do you read my question before comment?

Comment: Sorry to dig up an old post, but I was looking for this too. However, if your Cordova CLI is not generating an xcode project, that is something you might want to look into.

Answer (score 2):

If the cordova app builds and runs on the simulator, try running `cordova run ios --device`

This worked for me, when before it was only hitting the simulator.

Alternatively, if that STILL doesn't work for you, when you run `codova build ios`, to just build the app, you could use itunes to sync the generated .app file in `<project_folder>/platforms/ios/build/device/AppName.app`

Comment: --device is the documented method https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an Apple CLI tool canned `xcodebuild`, as well as this wrapper around it by Facebook. I'd suggest trying out either that or look at the build-in `xcodebuild` shipped with xcode.

Hopefully one of them will work.

- https://github.com/facebook/xctool
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html

Comment: The Cordova CLI already has a dependency on the xcodebuild CLI, which is how it is able to build an run on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Cordova CLI, you should be able to do this:
cordova run ios

Comment: This doesnt help getting it directly onto the physical device... only runs the simulator.

Comment: You have to change the target in XCODE to real device and not the simulator.

Comment: Right, but the point was NOT using xcode, using the CLI only. In xcode, the physical device is already specified, but running `cordova run ios` still opens the simulator.

Comment: You can try "cordova run ios --device" maybe

Comment: Late response, but `cordova run ios --device` works like a charm. Awesome!